# Availability Calendar - Most Efficient - PHP/MySql/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, performance, calendar

A set of employees (less then 2000) need to select their availability (pick multiple dates) during the year. 
I need to save that availability and after select the employees available for a specific event (filter by start date and end date). I want those who are fully available and partially available.

When the employees select their availability the most efficient way is to save day by day or by date blocks?

The table should be rather simple: DATE & Person_ID .

Did someone created something similar? What do you think it's the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL is the least flexible language; your task needs flexibility.

Use SQL to do some filtering, but then use PHP or JavaScript to do the real work.